# angularjs: how to load remote common data once and share it across controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angularjs app, I want to load just once a huge list of data, and share it across controllers. 
So I have a factory that retrieve data over http:

```
angular.module('app').factory('reportFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var reportFactory = {};
        reportFactory.endPoint = 'ajax.php';
        reportFactory.getHugeData = function () {
            return $http.get(this.endPoint + '?query=CourseListQuery');
        };
        return reportFactory;
    }]);
```

I tried this:

```
angular.module('app').factory('CommonData', ['reportFactory', function CommonDataFactory(reportFactory) {
    var data = {};
    reportFactory.getHugeData().then(function (response) {
        data.courses = response.data;
    }, function (error) {
    });
    return data;

}]);
```

but then when in my controller I tried to access `log.warn(CommonData.courses);`, I got `undefined`

I would like to store the result of that promise  to get it available to all my angularjs app.

How to structure that and where to make the unique call that will retrieve data?

Comment: Use a function in the factory to get the `data.courses`

Comment: You defined "getHugeData", but you called "getCourseList".

Comment: @Ramsing Nadeem: this was a typo before posting on this site. fixed. thanks.

Comment: @Ramsing Nadeem: could you provide a detailed snippet?

Comment: Don't know how your code looks like; share a Plunker here; shall debug it.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is related to your api/asynchronous call. log.warn(CommonData.courses) maybe is being executed before that CommonData.courses is being populated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a provider.

```
angular.provider("CommonData", [function() {
    this.commonData = {};

    this.setCommonData = function(commonData) {
        this.commonData = commonData;
    };

    this.getCommonData = function() {
        return this.commonData;
    };
}]);
```

Then in the controller:

```
angular.controller("ExampleController", ['CommonDataProvider', function(CommonDataProvider) {
    var commonData = CommonDataProvider.getCommonData();
}]);
```